# URL alias with taxonomy term (multiple vocabularies). How do I choose one?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, uri, path-aliases

I'm trying to setup a content type that has a multiple level taxonomy vocabulary assigned. The same content has a CCK taxonomy field for other use, but I don't want to use it on the URL.

The problem is that when I put in the URL alias "[term]/[title-raw]," it selects the CCK field, not the vocabulary assigned through the Taxonomy module. I tried to change the order  of the fields, but nothing changes.

What can I do, apart from putting the other vocabulary through CCK as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[term]` -- Name of top taxonomy term

Top taxonomy term is the term with the lowest weight from the vocabulary with the lowest weight.

Reorder vocabularies at `admin/content/taxonomy`, move the desired one to the top and you should be good. :-)

Comment: wooow, you're genious :) It really works :) I haven't really thought of changing the weight on the taxonomy list, but on the display fields order only.. Thank you